# Cannot Import External Library

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I kept track of the instructions in that [link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib#how-to-build-opencv-with-extra-modules). I downloaded the repository. Then, I applied those commands:

```
cd C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build 
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\opencv_contrib-master\modules C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\sources
```

It creates an CMakeError.txt file including lots of errors.

Related parts:

```
Build FAILED.

"C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_93c95.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fseeko referenced in function _main [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_93c95.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_93c95.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_93c95.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)

    2 Error(s)


Build FAILED.

"C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_6e125.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_6e125.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)


Build FAILED.

"C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3a774.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(19): error C2065: 'off64_t' : undeclared identifier [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3a774.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(20): error C2065: 'off64_t' : undeclared identifier [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3a774.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(21): error C2065: 'off64_t' : undeclared identifier [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3a774.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(22): error C2065: 'off64_t' : undeclared identifier [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3a774.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(23): error C2065: 'off64_t' : undeclared identifier [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3a774.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)

    5 Error(s)



Build FAILED.

"C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_0f669.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jbg_newlen referenced in function _main [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_0f669.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_0f669.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_0f669.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)

    2 Error(s)



Build FAILED.

"C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_2f0ec.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(Link target) -> 

  CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mmap referenced in function _main [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_2f0ec.vcxproj]

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_2f0ec.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_2f0ec.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)

    2 Error(s)



Build FAILED.

"C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_4b3e8.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory [C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_4b3e8.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and coding in c++ with OpenCV3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-extract opencv and follow the steps of the following two links:

[Install OpenCV 3.0 on Windows 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFtefHEEII)

[Create an Visual Studio (2013) Project with openCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHX3MLzwF6Q)

Let me know if that works for you..

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect open cv version and vs2013. i hope it fits your comment